# Exponential notation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting the error below, because a floating-point value is contained in the CSV file that uses exponential notation.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 1 in record 0 is not a valid float: 9.403954980927348E-39
     [[Node: DecodeCSV = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], field_delim=",", na_value="", use_quote_delim=true](arg0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_1, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_2, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_3, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_4, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_5, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_6, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_7, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_8, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_9, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_10, decodecsv_placeholder, decodecsv_placeholder_1, decodecsv_placeholder_2, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_14, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_15, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_16, decodecsv_placeholder_3, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_18, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_19, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_20)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

I'm using the following for the field default:

```
[0.0]
```

How can I fix this?  Not all the values will necessarily use this 'E notation'.

Comment: How do you read your csv? Pandas?

Comment: 9.403954980927348E-39 is a really large integer!